# How can I gzip compress js files on S3 and serve them via CloudFront on AWS?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, gzip, amazon-cloudfront

I have a file larger than 10mb that I want to compress using gzip and serve through cloudfront.
I need the whole process to be done automatically, as it's a part of our CI pipeline.
I have managed to manually compress the file, but then failed to add the required metadata `Content-Encoding: gzip`.

Adding it using `aws s3 cli` attached it as "User defined" instead of "System defined", and CloudFront didn't add that header.

I have read the docs that state that System defined metadata can be set only via the Console.

So my question is, how can I automate this process?